# Not a developer - How do I approach database project?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I'm a marketing professional with some experience pertaining to databases (some architecture but mainly querying), coding (HTML, CSS, light python dev many years ago), an understanding of how APIs work, etc... but I'm not a web developer.

I'm trying to figure out how to get data from our ExactTarget data views into a an external database.  I've been able to create a MySQL database via Amazon RDS, but I do not know how to populate the tables with data from our ExactTarget data views.  I'm currently exploring Marketing Cloud's python API starter kit but frankly I'm not sure if this is where I should be looking.

Can anybody give me advice on topics I'll need to study and ExactTarget resources I'll need to work with in order to accomplish the above?

Thank you,
Eugene

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)? Just google-fu here, I don't have much ET knowledge myself. Python is definitely more accessible than `Apex` though. :)

Comment: I've taken a look at [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).  I've been able to successfully run a couple queries, but data views only retain the previous 6 months of history.  I'm hoping to be able to programatically fetch data from the ExactTarget data views into our MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

[Tracking Data Extracts](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/using_tracking_extracts/) are what you need.  You can dump out whatever range of activity data you want -- beyond the 6 month limitation of the System Data Views.

You'll want to do it on some interval with an Automation using a rolling date range so the files aren't huge.

The results are dropped in the Export directory of your FTP share.  If you set up your own File Location, you can have the `.zip` file transferred to the FTP site of your choosing.

I'd suggest configuring the Data Extract and File Transfer Activities in SFMC directly, not with the API.  You can execute the these activities, but beyond that, I wouldn't recommend trying to build anything more with the API for this amount of data.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. 

Are you suggesting that we use Tracking Extracts because we are able to dump data beyond the 6 month limitation of Data Views, or because it's perhaps a more efficient solution than the API route due to the amount of data we'll be pulling (lots of it)?  

Do you have any advice on how and where we should be maintaining the data dumps?  We do not have a connected CRM yet, nor do we have an internal database to connect to, which is why I'm exploring how we might integrate with Amazon RDS.

Comment: Tracking Extracts are definitely more efficient.  The data can certainly be dumped in your SFMC FTP location, but how you consume it is up to you.  If Amazon RDS gives you a way to FTP files and houses a database, that'll work.  I use a local Filezilla and MS SQL Server running on my laptop.  Depending on your send volume these files can be very large.